# VLookup arranged into cell based on neighbor cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I am looking for a way to do a VLookup that will call information from Google Sheet 2 into Google Sheet 1. Specifically, if cell H in 'Google Sheet 1' matches cell A in 'Google Sheet 2', it will put the information from cell B in 'Google Sheet 2' into the corresponding row in 'Google Sheet 1'.

Example is below:

Before function:

Google Sheet 1:
     H        I
1  Eng#1   (Blank)
2  Eng#2   (Blank)
3  Eng#3   (Blank)
4. ENG#4   (Blank)

Google Sheet 2:
    A         B
1  Eng#1     .4
2  Eng#2     .1
3  Eng#4     .7
4. Eng#7     .3
5. Eng#3     .2

Result I am seeking:

Google Sheet 1:
     H         I
1  Eng#1      .4
2  Eng#2      .1
3  Eng#3      .2
4. Eng#4      .7
5. Eng#7      .3

I would very much appreciate assistance with this, as it would be a way to increase efficiency and tracking for a group of people.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to combine VLOOKUP and IMPORTRANGE.  Try something like:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(H:H="",,VLOOKUP(H:H,IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","Sheet1!AB:AC"),2,0)))`

Note that it may be necessary to try the IMPORTRANGE on its own first, to ensure that the Sheets have the correct access to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need is an IF statement which you can then drag down vertically to all of column H -

```
=IF(H1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!H2,"")
```

You can copy and paste it to H4,H6,H8 etc and the cell references will change for you

if you are matching H1 against any row of column A use

```
=VLOOKUP(H1,Sheet2!A$1:A$100,2,false)
```

dragging this vertically will keep it referring to cells A1:A100 in Sheet2 but it can be copied/pasted to different cells horizontaly (cell references will change for you)